# How can we add multiple values in the same field in Realtime database firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So, I want to compare the postalcode with the value I will enter in my database i.e firebase, but if taking future changes in mind, how can I add more postalcode values so that the editext can compare it with.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question/problem. If you'r not helped by reading the documentation on [adding to a list of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data), can you edit your question to show: 1) the data that you have in the database? 2) the code that writes that data? 3) the data that yuo'd instead like to get in the database3? -- I also recommend reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond with @.